# Does exporting from a CMS-based site to another site affect Google ranking?

Tags: seo, cms, google-ranking, migration

Scenario:

1. I run a blog on a CMS-based platform (like WordPress) and I purchase a domain.
2. After some time I will purchase a host service from a web company and I want to import there the entire blog from the CMS-based platform (WordPress in this case) by keeping everything (domain name, content, top-level domanin extension/s…), so that the blog will be identical to the original except for no longer being holded by WordPress.

By going from the CMS-based platform to any other kind of site **will I lose** the places I reach on **Google ranking** in the intervening period?

Comment: I am a bit confused. Are you talking about going from mysite.wordpress.com to mysite.com??

Comment: @closetnoc No, I mean moving from my wordpress site to another host server...

Comment: Assuming you use a quality host, there should no issue at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as all of the URLs you currently have resolve correctly and 301 redirects are created for the URLs that change, Google will be just fine with the switch.

Google doesn't care how you serve your pages as long as they load, are fast, are mobile friendly, etc...

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to post this as a comment but I am lacking reputation points to do it, I want to give you recommendation before you transfer the site.

Use WP Migrate DB to export the database, since wordpress got serialized data to handle and it involves the links so if you use normal export you will either have to deal with lots and lots of links or you will have them broken, wp migrate db plugin handles this serialized data and do it really well you can save your current link structure and the links wouldn't change since you are about to use the same domain it shouldn't be a problem for your website ranking, also know the difference between 301 and 302 redirects before you use them, 301 redirect basically means Temporary moved page and 302 means permanently moved page if you aren't going to use the redirected page again you should do a 302 redirect, you can check your redirects online by typing redirect checker in Google there are few good tools for that.